# Different behaviors in render without www in url

Tags: asp.net, url, query-string, redirect

I have an issue on my website.
It seems that a page has different behaviors when the URL contains (or not) the "www".
It looks like it remove all my query strings

```
http://example.com/test.aspx?name=John
```

This URL redirect to : `http://www.example.com/test.aspx`

The project is on ASP.NET 4.0 (Webforms)

Comment: That's not a "standard" problem, check you have any redirect rules that could be causing that.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I already checked my rules, and none of them deal with the www.
I also tried to force the www in the URL, but it did not work.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the redirect rules (or a redirect somewhere on test.aspx), whether you think it's related or not. Double check and describe any redirect rules that might be in effect here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in IIS? Do you happen to have the UrlRewriteModule running? Perhaps there are some rewrite rules in your web.config that are performing redirects and dropping the query string. If present, you would see check under the 'system.webServer' tag an entry called 'rewrite' containing your rules:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <rewrite
    <rules>
      <!-- make sure there are no undesired rules here doing redirects -->
      <rule...
```

Comment: We do have several rules that rewrite the URL. We checked one by one if any of them could raise this problem, unsuccefully. 
The problem is that we change the URL format recently, and work on the code to redirect the old one via the query strings.
Maybe we should make an other rule which can get the query strings in the url and redirect me according to them. Should we try this kind of rule ?

`<conditions><add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="qs=(.*)" /></conditions>`